# POST to page with headers using Perl

Tags: perl

I have a problem. I asked this question yesterday but not the way I really wanted it to be done, so my apologies. What I want to do is post to a page email and password but that page also requires specific headers to be sent. (I believe they are called request headers). I tried LWP::UserAgent but I could only post data, not the headers with it. How would I do this? I am new to Perl. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What headers? Is it a REST API? Where is the code you have now?

Comment: its a test link I want to send lets say to login.php with username and password or email and password, but I also want to send page headers

Answer (score 1):

You previously mentioned the user Agent and cookies. While you could add those to the request, that's usually something you want over multiple requests and thus can be set in the UA itself.

```
use HTTP::Cookies         qw( );
use HTTP::Request::Common qw( POST );
use LWP::UserAgent        qw( );

my $cookies = HTTP::Cookies->new();
$cookies->set_cookie(...);

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(
   agent      => ...,
   cookie_jar => $cookies,
);

my $request = POST(
   'http://www.example.com/',
   Referer => '...',
   Content => [
      username => ...,
      ...
   ],
);

my $response = $ua->request($request);
```

Comment: is this only for cookies? let say I want to send referrer and other components, where do i put them?

Comment: And I imagine the cookie string would go instead of $cookies?

Comment: Instead of `$ua->request(POST ...)` you can simply do `$ua->post(...)`.

Comment: I actually got this to work. I will post the answer to my question.

Answer (score -1):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent qw( );

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
$ua->default_header('Cookie' => '...');
$ua->default_header('Referer' => '...');

my $response = $ua->post('url_goes_here', {username=>'test', password=>'pass'});

if($response->is_success)
{
 print $response->as_string;
}
```

this worked for me. Hopefully someone can learn a thing or two from this answer. The trick is to use `default_header`

Comment: Please explain to me why a downvote. That code worked for me, compared to other's which didn't.